# Difference between certificate of a website and a SAML certificate?

Tags: certificate

A browser certificate is a signed document and with the public key of the CA, my user agent is able to validate it.

In the metadata file of SAML, there is also a certificate, but it just seems to be something else. What is it and what is it exactly for?

Answer (score 2):

It's used to *produce* a signed document. The certificate that's in the IdP's metadata is used to sign the SAML tokens ("assertions") that are issued by the identity provider (IdP) and transferred to the service provider (SP).

As the assertion is transferred through the user's web browser, it has to be protected against the user tampering with it (e.g. so that the user couldn't add more groups or other attributes), so it is digitally signed using the IdP's private key, and the SP verifies that signature before allowing you to log in.

In other words, if SAML assertions are roughly equivalent of signed JWT tokens in OIDC, then the certificates are used like JWT signing keys.

<sub>*(Actually, you could perhaps call the SAML assertion a "certificate" and the issuing IdP a "certification authority"...)*</sub>

---

Additionally, the SP could also have its own certificate, which the IdP could use to *encrypt* the assertion (e.g. if it contains internal data that shouldn't leak to the user, like shadowban status, or just to minimize exposure, like SSNs). This is optional.

Another reason for SPs to have their own certificates is so that they could sign *logout requests* that are sent back to the IdP. The SAML2 protocol supports "single logout", where logging out from one SP logs you out from all others as well as the IdP itself, but this protocol involves a long chain of redirects through locations that might not necessarily trust each other.

---

Side note: Even though certificates in SAML are the same kind of "signed document" as in TLS, one big difference is that in most cases, SAML certificates are self-signed and the SP only cares about the exact public key, ignoring all other fields. (Really, the biggest reason X.509 certificates are used is because SAML uses the pre-existing XML-DSig standard, and all tools/libraries expect to deal with certificates.) Though this is not to say that they *couldn't* be CA-issued; that's supported but rarely needed.

Comment: So the certificate is a private key? If so, the metadata file is data which should no get public, correct? Why are there websites for checking the correctness of a metadata file?

Comment: No, it's not. Certificates always hold the *public* key; them being used in SAML vs TLS does not change anything about how they actually work. The IdP uses the corresponding private key to sign the assertion, and the SP uses the certificate's public key to verify it.

Comment: But then what is the public key for in the metadafile of the IDP?

Comment: You mean a public key *other than* the certificate?

Comment: I mean the certificate in the metadata file.

Comment: The certificate in IdP's metadata is used to verify assertions signed by the IdP, like I already said. The certificate in SP's metadata is used either to encrypt the assertions sent to that SP, and/or to verify SLO requests signed by the SP, or not used at all.

Comment: But why should the IDP verify it is own assertions? The IDP creates an assertion and sends it to the SP. Why the step of verifying? It sounds unnecessary to me to verify my own message. What am i still not getting here?

Comment: The IdP isn't verifying them, the SP is. I mean, it's not the IdP that consumes its own metadata either -- the IdP's metadata is consumed by the SP, and vice versa. That way the IdP's certificate is known by the SP, and so on.